# Another postgres not starting: "could not map anonymous shared memory"

Tags: linux, postgresql, amazon-ec2, shared-memory, postgresql-10

I noticed there are several questions about Postgres (10) not able to boot because of the shared memory; despite that I couldn't really make it run. Now everytime I try to start the cluster I keep getting this error:

```
2021-10-24 10:13:43.269 UTC  [11253] FATAL:  could not map anonymous shared memory: Cannot allocate memory
2021-10-24 10:13:43.269 UTC  [11253] HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded available memory, swap space, or huge pages. To reduce the request size (currently 5507432448 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing shared_buffers or max_connections.
```

I tryed to check and modify the kernel shmall parameter, but didn't work.

```
~$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmall
18446744073692774399
```

```
~$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
18446744073692774399
```

I can't reduce the memory into the config file because these are the settings I must use although I  tryied anyway but without success (I even used the minimum values).

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT 1**:

Ok, I found something strange:

1. I purged postgresql completely from the system
2. I reinstalled postgresql
3. Started the cluster and everything went well
4. Stopped the cluster and edited the configuration file with the settings I need
5. Tryed to start the cluster again but got the same error
6. Reverted back to the default configuration file but still getting the same error. Why is this happening?

The system has 16 GB of RAM.

**EDIT 2: ADDING DETAILS**

Ok so basically I had to migrate a postgresql database by moving the data directory. That's the only thing it could be done. After moving the data folder completely here's the error.
I noticed there weren't a swap memory so I created it but still same error.

The shared memory and segment between the two server are basically identical. When I start the cluster It immediately fails, so maybe this can be a clue for you. The destination server is an EC2 machine.

I don't know what else I can do..

**EDIT 3: OTHER DETAILS**

This is what the command lsipc shows:

```
RESOURCE DESCRIPTION                                              LIMIT USED  USE%
MSGMNI   Number of message queues                                 32000    0 0.00%
MSGMAX   Max size of message (bytes)                               8192    -     -
MSGMNB   Default max size of queue (bytes)                        16384    -     -
SHMMNI   Shared memory segments                                    4096    0 0.00%
SHMALL   Shared memory pages                       18446744073692774399    0 0.00%
SHMMAX   Max size of shared memory segment (bytes) 18446744073692774399    -     -
SHMMIN   Min size of shared memory segment (bytes)                    1    -     -
SEMMNI   Number of semaphore identifiers                          32000    0 0.00%
SEMMNS   Total number of semaphores                          1024000000    0 0.00%
SEMMSL   Max semaphores per semaphore set.                        32000    -     -
SEMOPM   Max number of operations per semop(2)                      500    -     -
SEMVMX   Semaphore max value                                      32767    -     -
```

These values are the same of the source machine I'm trying to migrate. The data directory is identical with the original one, but everythime I go with this command:

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster 10 main start
```

I get the same error. I really need help!

Comment: It should *al least* work with the default config file.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I replaced my config file with the original one but still I get the same error.

Comment: Does the reported number 5507432448 change when you change the memory settings? If not, then the config file you are changing is not the correct one.

Comment: Yes, with the default configuration file that value is smaller.

Comment: What does `ipcs -a` show ?

Comment: Actually it sows nothing

Comment: I updated the main thread with the result of the command lsipc

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/kernel-resources.html#SYSVIPC) says:

> By default, PostgreSQL allocates a very small amount of System V shared memory, as well as a much larger amount of anonymous `mmap` shared memory.

So unless you changed [`shared_memory_type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-SHARED-MEMORY-TYPE) to `sysv`, your kernel configuration is pretty irrelevant.

I can think of two possible reasons for the error:

- The kernel does not have enough memory available to satisfy the request. This could be because `shared_buffers` is set too large, or because other processes use too much memory, or because there is already a lot of shared memory mapped for other purposes.
- You configured `huge_pages = on`, but there are no huge pages defined.

Comment: Ok, thank you for answering; At the moment the shared_buffers has a value of 128 MB and the dynamic_shared_memory_type is sysv.

Still getting the same error.

Comment: You could change the setting back to the default `mmap`. Then you don't have to fiddle with Systam V shared memory settings.

Comment: It was set on POSIX before, but still the same issue.

Comment: Then you don't have the required memory on your machine. Perhaps you are in a limited environment.

Comment: Thanks again for your time. I edited the post because I found something weird happening. I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. As you working with Postgresql DB you should create/provide swap space with same size or bigger than shared_buffers value.

How to create swapfile (ex. 8GB):

```
sudo fallocate -l 8G /.swapfile; sudo chmod 600 /.swapfile; sudo mkswap /.swapfile; sudo swapon /.swapfile;
```

then add swapfile to /etc/fstab:

```
/.swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting my server fixed this for me

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was `postgresql.auto.conf` file I've created myself with the `ALTER SYSTEM` command.
Cleaning up this file contents reset settings to system default and error fixed.